# How do I run the command `lsblk | grep disk` on my chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

I'm trying to get *Chrubuntu* onto an external HDD (500GB), so I can dual boot *Ubuntu* on my *Acer C710* SSD (16GB).

I was looking throgh the *Chrubuntu* documentation and it says I might need to specify the device name of my external drive, which can be found by running

```
lsblk | grep disk
```

I did run it in `crosh` on the chrome terminal but all I get is

```
unkown commmand lsblk
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move into your shell by typing

```
shell
```

Then, you type

```
sudo lsblk | grep disk
```

in it and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. It should work after that.